# Need advice about filtering DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, filter

I'm using .NET 3.5, C#, and WinForms.

My grid has lots of columns: SellerName, BuyerName, LoadType, LoadName, DriverName, CarSerialNumber, etc. I want to filter the BindingSource. I did this using ComboBoxes which is filled on DropDown with the grid cells' values, but it's not practical and makes for a bad-looking form.

I need advice on what is the best way to let the user choose values of the grid and then filter with a button. Can I make it like in Excel? There is a button on the column header, and when the user presses it, it shows a little menu with a checked list box. When the user checks any values and press a button it begins filtering.

Please advise me something.

This is pic of Excel:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,
first of all you should create your custom filter usercontrol, as similar as you wish to the one in excel.

Secondly, it's not easy to do, but you could add filter buttons to the grid (simply doing `grid.Controls.Add(...)`) and keep them aligned with columns' headers by overriding `OnColumnWidthChanged/OnColumnHeadersHeightChanged` of `DatagridView`.

Finally, when user clicks on filter button, you can open a `ToolStripDropDown` with your custom filter embedded in it, I mean something similar to this answer (obviously with your control instead of the listview):
[DropDown Menu with ScrollBar in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171640/dropdown-menu-with-scrollbar-in-net/3172041#3172041)

---

**EDIT:**

Here's a (working) code sample:

**Custom Column Header Cell Class:**

```
public class DataGridFilterHeader : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
{
    PushButtonState currentState = PushButtonState.Normal;
    Point cellLocation;
    Rectangle buttonRect;

    public event EventHandler<ColumnFilterClickedEventArg> FilterButtonClicked;

    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics,
                                  Rectangle clipBounds,
                                  Rectangle cellBounds,
                                  int rowIndex,
                                  DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState,
                                  object value,
                                  object formattedValue,
                                  string errorText,
                                  DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
                                  DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
                                  DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds,
                   cellBounds, rowIndex,
                   dataGridViewElementState, value,
                   formattedValue, errorText,
                   cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

        int width = 20; // 20 px
        buttonRect = new Rectangle(cellBounds.X + cellBounds.Width - width, cellBounds.Y, width, cellBounds.Height);

        cellLocation = cellBounds.Location;
        // to set image/ or some other properties to the filter button look at DrawButton overloads
        ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics,
                                  buttonRect,
                                  "F",
                                  this.DataGridView.Font,
                                  false,
                                  currentState);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsMouseOverButton(e.Location))
            currentState = PushButtonState.Pressed;
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsMouseOverButton(e.Location))
        {
            currentState = PushButtonState.Normal;
            this.OnFilterButtonClicked();
        }
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }
    private bool IsMouseOverButton(Point e)
    {
        Point p = new Point(e.X + cellLocation.X, e.Y + cellLocation.Y);
        if (p.X >= buttonRect.X && p.X <= buttonRect.X + buttonRect.Width &&
            p.Y >= buttonRect.Y && p.Y <= buttonRect.Y + buttonRect.Height)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    protected virtual void OnFilterButtonClicked()
    {
        if (this.FilterButtonClicked != null)
            this.FilterButtonClicked(this, new ColumnFilterClickedEventArg(this.ColumnIndex, this.buttonRect));
    }
}
```

**Custom Event Args:**

```
public class ColumnFilterClickedEventArg : EventArgs
{
    public int ColumnIndex { get; private set; }
    public Rectangle ButtonRectangle { get; private set; }
    public ColumnFilterClickedEventArg(int colIndex, Rectangle btnRect)
    {
        this.ColumnIndex = colIndex;
        this.ButtonRectangle = btnRect;
    }
}
```

**DataGridView Override:**

```
public class DataGridWithFilter : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnColumnAdded(DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var header = new DataGridFilterHeader();
        header.FilterButtonClicked += new EventHandler<ColumnFilterClickedEventArg>(header_FilterButtonClicked);
        e.Column.HeaderCell = header;
        base.OnColumnAdded(e);
    }

    void header_FilterButtonClicked(object sender, ColumnFilterClickedEventArg e)
    {
        // open a popup on the bottom-left corner of the
        // filter button
        // here's we add a simple hello world textbox, but you should add your filter control
        TextBox innerCtrl = new TextBox();
        innerCtrl.Text = "Hello World !";
        innerCtrl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 30);

        var popup = new ToolStripDropDown();
        popup.AutoSize = false;
        popup.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        popup.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        ToolStripControlHost host = new ToolStripControlHost(innerCtrl);
        host.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        host.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        host.AutoSize = false;
        host.Size = innerCtrl.Size;
        popup.Size = innerCtrl.Size;
        popup.Items.Add(host);

        // show the popup
        popup.Show(this, e.ButtonRectangle.X, e.ButtonRectangle.Bottom);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Filter Image]

---

**EDIT 2:**

Here's a full VS2008 project sample (DataGrid with customized filter, not just "Hello World"): --> http://www.mediafire.com/?s6o8jmpzh0t82v2

Comment: i cant add button it is on grid and only one i want to be at left side of all column header text. datagridview1.Controls.Add(btnFiler);

Comment: You're (partially) right, I managed to do what you need, using a custom `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`. Look my edit, I really hope this helps (It was a bit tiring).  ;)

Comment: wow. its too late i will sleep happy and do this tomorrow. You the best. im so happing. im trying to do something since "answered 14 hours ago" but nothing ....  Thank you thank you so much.

Comment: i cant use this code :( i dont no where to insert and how to call

Comment: Just create 3 files with the 3 classes I posted. Then use `DataGridWithFilter` instead of the usual `DataGridView`. You should even see a `DataGridWithFilter` item in the designer toolbox after a project compilation, so you can just drag n drop it on your form if you want. Otherwise add it to your form programmatically.

Comment: i tried it thanks but cant fill popup with strings which is dgv. i did not wanted to disturb you. it was best way-out from my problem. I was makeing lisview popup with this grid.

Comment: OK, I did a small but complete VS2008 project, here's the link: http://www.mediafire.com/?s6o8jmpzh0t82v2  
I really hope this help.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the project above contains a full working filter example, not a simple "Hello World", therefore I highly suggest you to have a look at it ;-)