# Problem when summing selected cells in DataGridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I using this code for sum selected cells. Its work good but when user selecte cell where is letter is throws exceptions : ) how can i secure when in selectet cells is letters dont make sum

Comment: Post Code. Accept more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e) 
    { 
        String filterStatus = DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell.GetFilterStatus(dataGridView1); 
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterStatus)) 
        { 
            showAllLabel.Visible = false; 
            filterStatusLabel.Visible = false; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            int result = -1;
            Int32.TryParse(filterStatus, out result);
            if (result != 0)
            {
                 // it is a number
                 showAllLabel.Visible = true; 
                 filterStatusLabel.Visible = true; 
                 filterStatusLabel.Text = filterStatus; 
            }
            else
            {
                 // it can be a number yet won't help you with adding
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You should look at the return value of TryParse and not the result (as zero IS a number!)

Comment: private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            String filterStatus = DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell.GetFilterStatus(dataGridView1);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterStatus))
            {
                showAllLabel.Visible = false;
                filterStatusLabel.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                showAllLabel.Visible = true;
                filterStatusLabel.Visible = true;
                filterStatusLabel.Text = filterStatus;
            }
        }

Comment: @Pabuc: Stuart is right, if filter status is `"0"` your code skip it, but `0` IS a number. You should get `bool isNum = Int32.TryParse(filterStatus, out result)` and use `isNum` in your `if`

Comment: yes it will skip it but why add 0 to your sum? x + 0 = x anyway??

Comment: Yes, in this case it's ok, but what if, for example, this code is reused for calculating `Average` ?

Comment: OP asked it for sum operation. In every other case, bool is better. Using bool in this case will add 1 more variable into your code which is not needed.

Comment: Well ok, but then you should remove your `// it is not a number` comment from the code because is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

this is my code

```
 private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        String filterStatus = DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell.GetFilterStatus(dataGridView1);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterStatus))
        {
            showAllLabel.Visible = false;
            filterStatusLabel.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            showAllLabel.Visible = true;
            filterStatusLabel.Visible = true;
            filterStatusLabel.Text = filterStatus;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are not summing anything here? I've edited my code but not sure if this is what you need..

Comment: Yes Pabuc is right, you're not summing here. By the way did you see my attached filter sample project, in the last edit of this answer? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243616/need-advice-about-filtering-datagrid/4243942#4243942