# Popup window in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, popup

I have a windows form application where I show information about products and product categories in a datagridview. I would like to create a popup window so when I right click on a product and choose add to category a popup window appears and in that I show all the categories in a dropdownbox and when I click a button the product add to the category.

I want to create a popup window with a dropdownbox and a button. How do I do that in a window form application?

Comment: 2 options IMHO: [ContextMenuStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aszetbbk.aspx) or a custom Popup ([example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171640/dropdown-menu-with-scrollbar-in-net/3172041#3172041))

Answer (score 8):

You can create a regular form, and call the `myPopupForm.ShowDialog()` method. The `ShowDialog` method blocks the main form, so the user can select a category, upon which you `Close()` the popup window; execution will continue on the main form.

More information can be found on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx#Y800.

Answer (score 1):

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
```

This method will be like the `Message.Show` method, but you can add Buttons, TextBoxes, etc. in the Designer tools.

```
form.ShowDialog();
```

This method will just bring up another form.

```
form.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

AddHandler Me.Click,AddressOf Me_Click

```
Private Sub Me_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   Dim popupForm As PopupForm = New PopupForm()
   popupForm.Show(Me)
End Sub
```

You may get an exception window.Click continue-popup window will come.For further clicks get as many popups as you click
Regards
kvinvisibleguy